# Why does one index work and the other does not?

Tags: mysql

I beg your pardon if this is an exceedingly stupid question, but I am new to MySQL. I have a fairly big database (70 GB) with a simple structure (just one table) which I intend to use for fast retrieval of records. As you can imagine, grepping a 70GB flat file is no fun.

In my first attempt, I created a table (nothing fancy, 1 ENUM, 4 unsigned INTs and 2 FLOATs). Since data retrieval without an index was slow, I created an index after the table had been filled with data, by using something like

```
create index myid_index on mytable (myid) using btree;
```

and after doing that, everything worked fine. Retrieval speed was ok for me. Then I noticed that I did a mistake with the imported data so I started over. This time, I defined the table with an index before actually filling the table. This is how I understood things should be done. The command was something like

```
create table mytable ( ... , myid INTEGER unsigned, ..., index USING BTREE (myid))
```

When I did this, an index was created, but it does not seem to work, i.e. the retrieval is way to slow. Apparently the index is not used.

The indices of both procedures have the same size and are displayed in the 'explain mytable' view totally identically. The only difference is that the index only works for me if it is defined after all of the data have been imported.

What am I doing wrong ? While we're at it, a 2nd question: When I define the index with the 'create index' command, i have to give it a name. What is this name used for? I don't have to specify it during the query, do I ?

Comment: "the index does not seem to work": the output of `EXPLAIN [your SELECT query here] ;` will show for sure whether MySQL uses the index. Please post it here in full if you need help in reading this report.

Comment: I now have two tables (one with index at define-time, the other with index made after data import). If have optimized the former, to no avail. Following above suggestion, I have run explain(query) and the results look similar. For the table with the post-hoc index, I get for both "possible_keys" and "key" the answer 'myid_index' (which is the name I defined during "create index". In the other example, I get for both "possible keys" and "key" the answer "myid" (which is probably due to the fact that I did not define an index name) apart from that the reports are the same.

Answer (score 3):

*tl;dr: since the below did not address the issue, more answers are welcome*

Actually, it is better to mass-import your data first, then create an index. By creating the index before the import, you forced MySQL to recompute the index after inserting each and every row (this is not *exactly* what happens in fact, but it is conceptually close). Conversely, if you create the index after import, then the index needs to be constructed only once.

As a result of the index being updated many times during your data import, fragmentation probably occured, hence the degraded performances. I would recommend issuing an [`OPTIMIZE TABLE [the_table]`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html) after your mass insertion.

As for your second question, specifying a name for an index is optional. MySQL creates one by default if you omit the clause. I would recommend specifying it explicitely though, it makes retrieval easier (eg. you need to specify the index name in a [DROP INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/drop-index.html) statement).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am currently 'optimizing' the table to see if this helps. This will probably take a few hours. When it is done I will also try to 'explain' the query (did not know that this is possible).

Comment: @user900889 Yes, this is likely to take a while, possibly even longer than if you just dropped and recreated the table altogether. Sorry, I forgot to mention that :)

Comment: I have run the optimization and (as shown in the commont below my question) the index appears to be used. Nevertheless, the answer takes forever (i.e. >10 minutex), while in the table with the late index generation the answer is given in a second.

Comment: optimization was faster than expected. Filling the table with data takes about 2h, indexing another 3h, optimizing was done in less than 1h. Too bad that it did not help.

Comment: Is the table InnoDB or MyISAM (if unsure: `SHOW CREATE TABLE [the_table]`, check the final `ENGINE=xxx` clause)? If InnoDB, are you  using one file per table (`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table'`). I do not have a solution at the moment, but this information might help others.

Comment: I am using MyISAM because I assume that this is faster and takes less storage space (I don't need the Innodb features). Maybe this was a wrong decision?

Comment: for the time being, I will just resort to use the table with the index created post hoc. This one does it for me.